# Failed to get schema for this query Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, tableadapter

I have a page in my program which has a `DataGridView` object on it.
It is populated by a query that selects data from the database table called DOCS.

The table has 4 columns:

1. applicant_name
2. doc_id
3. doc_name
4. doc_contents

I'm trying to add a delete query for a user to delete a document from the table when they select it and hit the 'delete' button.

When I try to create the delete query, I get the

> "Failed to get schema for this query"

message and I can't understand why.

My query looks like this:

```
DELETE FROM DOCS
WHERE        (doc_id = @Param3)
```

Could anyone explain why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Show how you call this query in c#

Comment: I haven't called it yet, I'm trying to add the query to the tableAdapter of the dataGridView and it won't even let me add it.

Comment: use this query for TableAdapter : DELETE FROM [DOCS] WHERE (([doc_id]=@Param3))

Comment: Unfortunately it still gives me the same error.

Comment: I ended up creating a query through the code and executing it through an SQLCommand object, by getting the selected row of the datagridview, retrieving the value of the doc_id through the selected row and adding it as a parameter to the query, which works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using data binding to load it from adapter, if yes pz check if I insert update delete statement is generated by adapter.

Comment: The checkboxes for those 3 are selected, i'm not sure how to access them though?